# Returning incorrect data from sql query using Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, timezone

I am having an issue where I need to fetch certain records based on the current user timezone. The timezone is stored and accessible, but one problem I am running into is that when I run a query in my PostgreSQL editor example:

```
WITH user_tz AS ( 
            SELECT sp.current_tz 
            FROM synced_profile sp 
            WHERE sp."owner" = '0026004a-9fce-455a-a53a-ced75c18323d' 
            AND (sp.deleted IS FALSE OR sp.deleted IS NULL) 
            AND sp.profile NOTNULL 
            LIMIT 1 
          ), 
          all_valid_activities AS ( 
            SELECT j.*, sp.image_url, 
            CASE WHEN content_message::jsonb->'activity_info'->'time_logged' = 'null' THEN NULL 
              ELSE (content_message::jsonb->'activity_info'->'time_logged')::TEXT::TIMESTAMPTZ 
            END AS time_logged, 
            tz.current_tz 
            FROM jccontent j 
            JOIN synced_profile sp ON j.account_id = sp.owner AND sp.profile NOTNULL AND (sp.first_name IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(sp.first_name) != '') AND (sp.last_name IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(sp.last_name) != '') 
            CROSS JOIN user_tz tz 
            WHERE content_type = 'a' AND account_type IS NOT NULL AND status = 'A' AND team_id = 41 
            AND DATE_TRUNC('day', j.created_at AT TIME ZONE tz.current_tz) = DATE_TRUNC('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE tz.current_tz) 
          )
SELECT * FROM all_valid_activities ;
```

This returns results, but when I run the same query calling from NodeJs in my API, it is returning no data. The queries are identical as well when I printed them out to compare. I am thinking maybe the issue might be due to timezone but not where which part as the same query is returning different results.

Thank you!

Comment: 1) Best guess here: `...  DATE_TRUNC('day', j.created_at AT TIME ZONE tz.current_tz) = ...`. 2) What is the type for `, j.created_at`?  3) What does `show timezone` return in the Postgres server? **Add answers as update to question**.